# My case statement is not returning the correct values

Tags: sql, netsuite

I'm new to SQL so this may be obvious, I'm trying to get a text value to separate two different locations for me, but the "case" function I'm using isn't returning the correct data. here's what it looks like.

```
case 
  when {purchaseorder.number} = "not null" and {purchaseorder.name} = 'Vendor A' 
    then 'Location 1' 
  else 
    'Location 2' 
end
```

This is a transaction search looking at sales orders, but I need it to reference the POs associated with them. Maybe the problem is because I'm trying to pull data from "Purchase Order Fields..."

Comment: Is this a dynamic field value or part of a saved search? what is the field type/formulat type  you are trying to populate?

Comment: Its part of a saved search, the field type is a text formula, and its grouped. The transaction type from the search parameters is an SO but I'm trying to pull PO data thats on a related record

Comment: @DanMoore I think you are using wrong fields here. Try using "tranid", "mainlinename" (if search), "vendor", "entity", etc.

Comment: @Nitish would that work even though the search is looking at sales orders? And how would I write that, I can't visualize it?

Comment: @danmoore It should work. PO and SO are connected with intercompany transactions or some other field, which I am not sure at this moment. But I have tried this before and it works. Try creating a saved search to directly pull some PO field in columns and check the joins using nlapiLoadSearch api. Once you have the correct joins, you can add them to your formula, with not null correction

Comment: @DanMoore PO are on the related record list or in some standard NetSuite field on your SO?

Comment: @Nitish they are listed in the related records. Maybe Im just looking at the wrong joins, but I use those same joins for other searches in criteria and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of = "not null", you should say

`case when ({purchaseorder.number} IS NOT NULL and {purchaseorder.name} = 'Vendor A') then 'Location 1' else 'Location 2' end`

`NULL` is not a value, therefore it cannot equal `=` or not equal `!=` anything. It is not the same as `= "not null"` which is a value.. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203463/what-is-the-difference-between-null-and-is-not-null-in-qgis-filter-expression) other stack overflow answer has a more detailed explanation.

A secondary problem appears that Netsuite might require you to wrap the conditions in parenthesis.

Comment: I tried this and it ended up returning an error where the fields are supposed to populate

Comment: Can you specify what the error message is?

Comment: "ERROR: Invalid Expression" I'm working in NetSuite is that maters. I read somewhere the SQL is written differently inside NetSuite?

Comment: Yeah but CASE statements are the same. Can you try wrapping it with parens, I'll edit my answer if that works case when ({purchaseorder.number} IS NOT NULL and {purchaseorder.name} = 'Vendor A') then 'Location 1' else 'Location 2' end

Comment: This comes back the same. as an invalid expression.